# g++: merge template member function instance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, optimization, g++

is there any way to have identical member functions of a templated class to be merged in the final binary? I have a class which may support specific features and depended on that, may require some additional steps inside of the member function:

```
template <uint32_t features>
class Driver {
   static bool set (uint32_t value) {
      /* do something required for every feature */
      if (features & Feature::A)
         /* do special things if Feature::A */
      /* do something required for every feature */
      if (features & Feature::B || features & Feature::C)
         /* do something special for either Feature::B or Feature::C */
      return true;
   }
   /* more, similar methods */
};
```

later in the code, I would then use calls like `Driver<Feature::A>::set` or `Driver<Feature::A | Feature::B>::set` depending on the actual available features. All this works well so far, only the emitted code compiled with `g++-5.4.0 -std=c++11 -O3` does not merge identical methods how I would like to use it. Having multiple functions in this class with major common parts among them, really blows up the size of the final binary. While using private functions for the common parts reduces the overhead of size but is not as friendly to read in my opinion:

```
template <uint32_t features>
class Driver {
    static void _set_common_0 (value) {
        /* do something required for every feature */
    }
    static bool set (uin32_t value) {
        _set_common_0 (value);
        if (features & Feature::A)
            _set_special_0 (value);
        _set_common_1 (value);
        if (features & Feature::B || features & Feature::C)
            _set_special_1 (value);
        return true;
   }
};
```

Also this introduces problems, if there is an 'early out' path in one of the special parts, which could formerly be done by a simple `return` and now would be somehow escalated from the sub-functions, introducing further checks depending on the return value of those sub functions...

What I would like to have, is that the compiler emits (on use) symbols for `Driver<Feature::B>::set` and `Driver<Feature::C>::set` but let them point to the same code location as they are identical by means of code. Any idea how I could do this? (preferably, staying with c++11 and not require features from a newer standard)

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am wondering, why the identical instruction sequences (produced here by template instances) are not combined by `gcc`. For my understanding, `-ftree-tail-merge` should at least substitute those with a jump to the same implementations/code sequence (e.q. `Driver<Feature::B>::set` and `Driver<Feature::C>::set`).

Comment: Do you really need a class template here? Because this is not how templates should be used: you are checking compile time constants in run time: `if (features & Feature::A)`

Comment: its not really a compile time constant. The features that should be used are runtime dependend and not known during compilation. Dependend on the runtime environment, I can use `Feature::A` or can not use it. The `Driver<X>::set` calls are not issued directly but by an function pointer which is assigned during initialization dependend on the detected features of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you've posted it's clear to me that you're misusing templates. The correct way is to define partial specializations of `Driver`:

```
template <uint32_t features>
class Driver; // There may be some default implementation, but it is not necessary

// Specialize for feature A only
template <>
class Driver<Feature::A> {
   bool set (uint32_t value) {
      /* do special things for Feature::A */
      /* do something required for every feature */
      return true;
   }
};

// Specialize for feature B only
template <>
class Driver<Feature::B> {
   bool set (uint32_t value) {
      /* do special things for Feature::B */
      /* do something required for every feature */
      return true;
   }
};

// Specialize for features A and B
template <>
class Driver<Feature::A | Feature::B> {
   bool set (uint32_t value) {
      /* do special things for Feature::A */
      /* do special things for Feature::B */
      /* do something required for every feature */
      return true;
   }
};
```

The benefit of the template approach is that you don't have runtime overhead due to checking if certain features are enabled. Of course, if there are many features, there will be a huge number of combinations of features; hence the bloat of output binary. That's why I'd recommend to get rid of class template and use a runtime function argument; for example, pass features to the constructor:

```
class Driver {
private:
   uint32_t features_;

public:
   Driver(uint32_t features) : features_(features) {}
   bool set (uint32_t value) {
      /* do something required for every feature */
      if (features_ & Feature::A)
         /* do special things if Feature::A */
      /* do something required for every feature */
      if (features & Feature::B || features & Feature::C)
         /* do something special for either Feature::B or Feature::C */
      return true;
   }
};
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit of your first solution to my given one. After constant folding, the code for a template instantiation will be the same - with the draw back, that the common parts has to be written multiple times (in each body) by your solution. With future changes, one is likely to miss one body which may introduce problems/errors.

The templates are used to reduce the runtime overhead, as I know which features are available at each invocation. I have *one* check at the begin to select the right control flow.
The question is, why `gcc` does not merge identical code parts.

Comment: You are right. That's why you don't need templates here and should use the second solution. I just gave an example of how templates *should* be used, if you decided that you need them.

Comment: With your second solution I introduce runtime checks which are not required/desired. I already now at compile time for each call to a function which features I have available, so this should be possible (or also is). The remain question is, how can I make `gcc` combine template instances that result in the same code. E.g. `Driver<Feature::B>::set` and `Driver<Feature::C>::set` will be identical, but emitted twice - causing twice the size.

And for the way you say I _should_ use templates: what is the benefit of your solution compared to mine (so that I shall use yours instead)?

Comment: The benefit is absence of runtime checks of features (that is, statements like `if (features & Feature::A)`). Which are present in your class template, and make template argument literally useless. If you care about performance that much, you may only hope that the compiler will optimize your template instantiations and remove unnecessary checks, which will take form of `if(true)` or `if(false)`. But I'd say this is ass-backward way of programming. For C++ < 17 you should have multiple hand-written template specializations; in C++17 you can use `if constexpr`.

Comment: If you really want to stick to the template solution, you may try to enable `-Os` optimization option in GCC. This may reduce the output binary size.

Comment: well. those checks are constant during compile time and thus eliminated by constant folding + dead code elimination.. so those checks will not harm as they will already be deleted during compilation. The `if constexpr` of C++17 **guaranties** that the argument is a constexpr/throws a error if not and allows ill-formed syntax in the not-taken-branch. But also a normal `if` is already handled by constant folding + dead code elimination... `-Os` does not change the merge of those functions :/